# How can i marked the Childeren Select in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

[image]

How can I choose the marked childeren in this HTML.
with sublist i chose only from indey to index or?
Is there another possibility for select?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved with the remove. 
Are there even better solution. I have done so

```
Elements childrenSub2_L1 = childNewSub2.children();
       childrenSub2_L1.remove(1);
       childrenSub2_L1.remove(2);
       childrenSub2_L1.remove(childrenSub2_L1.size()-1);
```